# What can my employer see if I’m on my email on my personal phone

Tags: encryption

Basically I have the outlook app on my phone, if I connect to work WiFi what can they see? For example the emails in my inbox can all of them be read? Or the emails I have sent from let’s say my home and are now in sent items can they see these or is it just the emails being received and sent on their network?

Comment: Does the company have installed anything in your phone?if no then no,as long as https.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my employer see my browsing history from my home?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223964/can-my-employer-see-my-browsing-history-from-my-home)

Comment: If you are not using your company's security keys to connect their wifi, or they have not installed any application which has read access to your emails they can't see anything from your device. Your email traffic just passes through their network and they can only see what IP addresses and ports you connected to.

Comment: I connect to work WiFi like a home router, it automatically connects me to their Internet but have nothing installed on my phone. I use outlook email.